# searching a string from html page in php

Tags: php, search, preg-match

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("http://localhost/traveller/index.html");
$regex = '$_POST[/"search"/]';    

if (isset($_POST["sub"])){
   if (preg_match($regex, $data)) {
    echo $regex;
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
}
?>

<form action="searching.php" method="POST">
    Search: <br>
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```

on running this program i get:

> **Warning** preg_match(): No ending delimeter '$' found on line 6.  not
>   found

what should i do now?

Comment: Your regex format is not correct: I guess it should be `$regex = '/$_POST\["search"\]/'; `

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

Your don't need the regular expression at all.

Here is the code for what you need.

Try this.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("http://localhost/traveller/index.html");

if (isset($_POST["search"])&&!empty($_POST["search"])) {
   $search_str = $_POST["search"];
   if (strpos($data,$search_str)!== false) {
      echo $search_str;
   }
   else {
      echo "not found";
   }
}
?>

<form action="searching.php" method="POST">
    Search: <br>
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```

Comment: after making the changes you told, only else part is being executed even if the string is present on that page

Comment: The regular expression is correct. There is nothing wrong with it. You can check the authenticity of the regular expression here at this [link](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iF7) http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iF7 

@adityaaundhekar you have written the complete program wrong. I will edit my answer now with the code. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://localhost/traveller/index.html");
$regex = $_POST["search"];    

if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
    if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($regex) . '/i', $data)) {
        echo $regex;
    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }
}
```